# How to enable cpplint for c files in syntastic VIM

Tags: c, vim, syntastic, cpplint

I am using cpplint with Syntastic on VIM, however I am not able to use cpplint for C files.

I enabled cpplint for cpp files using the following line in .vimrc file:

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_cpplint_exec = 'cpplint'
```

I tried using the same for c:

```
let g:syntastic_c_cpplint_exec = 'cpplint'
```

But it does not help. The SyntasticInfo command still does not list cpplint as a available checker.

Comment: (1) `cpplint` only makes sense for C++.  (2) Setting the `*_exec` doesn't enable a checker (hint: reading the manual can save you a lot of time).

Comment: It's :SyntasticInfo, not :SynstasticInfo. Did you mistype this?

Comment: @HeronYang Sorry that's a typo. I did use SyntasticInfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'cpplint' isn't included in the list of syntax checkers for C which are used by Syntastic: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C. You can use only avrgcc, checkpatch, clang_check, clang_tidy, cppcheck, gcc, make, oclint, pc_lint, sparse, splint for C.